# Can I transfer a high quality video to my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, video, file-transfer

I'm a filmmaker who shoots Super-8, 16 and 36mm film.
Cameras shoot between 15 and 80 frames per second and the frames are later scanned one by one in 4k or 8k scanners. Each frame has grain and texture and basic compression models that work for digital do not work for film.

I've been trying for the past 4 hours to export a file format from my MacBook to my iPhone that the iPhone would be able to read, with no luck.

Things I've tried include:

-Sending the file to myself using the Messages app (received a different video file, highly compressed that looked very bad);

-Using a file transfer app like Send Anywhere [(file transfer error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQZjP.jpg);

-Using a file hosting app like Box ([another error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mxs7.jpg));

-Various different types of file formats, pixel sizes and compression bitrates (nothing that looked good worked)

The HD file is 3530x2946 and 22Mb. Another one that also didn't work was 1920x1600. I exported it from After Effects by manually setting bitrate because most Adobe Media Encoder presets were compressing it in a visually damaging way.

In conclusion, it seems that only highly compressed video files will transfer to the iPhone.

My current workaround is to have the HD file play in the Box app and do a recorded screenshot of the video playing, which I then had to trim and crop to remove black edges, but the "swipe up" line of the iPhone overlays the video so it's very far from ideal.

Can someone transfer a high bitrate video to be viewed on an iPhone, if yes what bitrate or export settings can I try?

Comment: Might be worthwhile to include the images as such instead of putting a link to imgur.com. SE uses i.stack.imgur.com, not imgur.com. You will need to re-import your photos using the built-in import tool (picture icon in editing toolbar), it will then do the job.

Comment: @Thinkr can you develop your comment? I don't see a "picture icon in editing toolbar" - is it an answer to my question or telling me how to add screenshots to the question?

Comment: It's telling you how to add screenshots to the question